# Crazy Bug in setDomainValueFormat

Tags: androidplot

I changed the sample code SimpleXYPlotActivity to format a domain label like this:

```
    // create a couple arrays of y-values to plot:
    Number[] domainLabels   = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8,  9, 10, 13, 14};
    Number[] series1Numbers = {1, 4, 2, 8, 4, 16, 8, 32, 16, 64};
    Number[] series2Numbers = {5, 2, 10, 5, 20, 10, 40, 20, 80, 40};

    // turn the above arrays into XYSeries':
    // (Y_VALS_ONLY means use the element index as the x value)
    //XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series1Numbers), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series1");
    XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(domainLabels), Arrays.asList(series1Numbers), "Series1");
    //XYSeries series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series2Numbers), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series2");
    XYSeries series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(domainLabels), Arrays.asList(series2Numbers), "Series2");

    //...other lines

    plot.setDomainValueFormat(new Format() {
      @Override
      public StringBuffer format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
        int day = ((Number) obj).intValue();
        System.out.println(day);
        return new StringBuffer(day);
      }
      @Override
      public Object parseObject(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
        return null;
      }
    });

    // reduce the number of range labels
    //plot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3);

    // rotate domain labels 45 degrees to make them more compact horizontally:
    plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelOrientation(-45);
```

I dont know why, but plot print the following domain labels:
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13
and not the right values...
1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14

Why has it this crazy behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Well to start, when I run the above code, no labels are printed at all.  But if I replace:

```
return new StringBuffer(day);
```

with:

```
return toAppendTo.append(day);
```

Then the labels appear.  Moving on...

Your formatter is truncating the floating point x-val associated with each domain tick label.  The reason you have this floating point component is because you are specifying your own xVals when you instantiate SimpleXYSeries. I suspect that what you really want is to specify iVals only, since you dont actually create xVals anywhere.

I made these changes:

First, create your XYSeries instances to create xVals from iVals like this:

```
XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series1Numbers), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series1");
XYSeries series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series2Numbers),SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series2");
```

Next, update your domain formatter to use your domain label lookup array like this:

```
plot.setDomainValueFormat(new Format() {
            @Override
            public StringBuffer format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
                int i = Math.round(((Number) obj).floatValue());
                return toAppendTo.append(domainLabels[i]);
            }
            @Override
            public Object parseObject(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
                return null;
            }
        });
```

For anyone wondering why obj is first converted to a float and then rounded to an int before being used as an iVal:  This is necessary to avoid the natural flooring behavior that occurs when converting float values to int values.  If for example you were to call intValue on a Double representation of 1, you'd get 0 because internally it's represented as 0.99999999... and gets floored to 0 by the conversion instead of being rounded up to 1.